# GIF Animations NOT Appearing

Tags: assets

I having a problem when trying to upload gif animations. It seems that the animation element doesn't work after they have been uploaded.

I looked at the Craft changelog and it mentioned something about support for gifs through ImageMagick. The site is on MediaTemple so when I used their ImageMagick install instructions it throws up an error.

> Internal Server Error
>
> curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set

I'm not sure if it is an ImageMagick thing or not but it is crucial to the function of the site. Its probably very simple.

Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're correct in that animated GIFs will only have their animations preserved if your server has [Imagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) installed.

If you're getting an error installing Imagick on MediaTemple, the you're better off contacting them with the error and seeing if they can help resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I think I got it functioning okay now as far as MediaTemple goes. Will Craft automatically detect ImageMagick?

Comment: Hi Brad, Its just stopped working again for some reason although its only the homepage. I'm really stuck with this as its an error I'm getting from Craft related to open_basedir. I can still use the other parts of the site and the Admin back-end. We have a big launch in 24hrs for an international BMX magazine built on Craft and they need to upload animated Gif adverts. Any help would be appreciated. Is it possible to disable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Comment: Yes, Craft will automatically detect Imagick. Either disable safe_mode in php.ini or remove the openbase_dir restrictions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918623/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated

Comment: Thanks brad, it seems that you need open_basedir in media temple to point to imagemagick, I did what they said in the KB article but it still doesn't seem to work. I'm trying media temple support to see if the will install it for me.

Comment: "I'm trying media temple support..." - famous last words. :)

Comment: This might not be the right place to ask but... I try anyways? Why isn't animated GIFs preserved even if the server only has GD? Are all images recreated somehow during upload? Does that happen to jpegs too? How does that affect quality?

Comment: Hi Brad, it seems that I can't use open_basedir with some of the craft plugins like OAUTH for video connections. The error is coming from these elements so when I set the open_basedir it throws up the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION error. It seems I can't use them both together. Funny thing is though that I can access the cp with the open_basedir in place for ImageMagick but when I upload a gif it still flattens it?? Not sure if the conflict is making the ImageMagick not work.

Comment: Hi Brad, I can't get this resolved at all. I think the only way is to change hosts and see if I can get ImageMagick running. I don't know if this helps but I'm getting this error.

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2014-04-04 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC Features: OpenMP imagick not installed
Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in /nfs/c11/h01/mnt/193568/domains/digbmx.com/html/img/imageTest.php on line 22

Comment: Is this extension required for ImageMagick to work with Craft:
 extension=magickwand.so

Comment: I don't think so? From the error it still sounds like Imagick isn't installed. I'd push back with MT... they should be able to help.

Comment: @AndréElvan Probably worth it's own separate question. :)

Comment: Hi Brad, Thanks for the help, I pushed MT but they only go as far as saying its installed so thats all we can do. I'm afraid my only other option is moving hosts to see if that works out better. Whatever way they have their set-up it means you have to open_basedir to let PHP interface with ImageMagick, but I can't do this when my plugins are using CURLOPT. The funny thing with the MT set-up is that I get the same result from my test wether I open_basedir or not. For me it sounds like its not installed properly on their servers, but they might not want to admit it?

Comment: Sounds about right. Not a big fan of MT at all.

Comment: Hi Brad, Would you have any recommendations on LA-based hosting, most of the audience is based there so it makes sense to locate in that part? I know this is something you may not want to mention on the forum here. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sorry... not aware of any based in LA, but I would think anywhere in U.S. would be fine.