# GIF animations garbled and static

Tags: assets, image

When I upload animated gif assets to a Craft site, they end up static and corrupted, as so:

[image: Holey Seagull]

([Original here](http://thumbpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/funny-gif-seagull-fighting-worm1.gif).)

My guess is that what's displayed is the last frame of the animation (which only contains pixels changed from the penultimate frame).

Other image resizing functions work. The site is hosted on a dedicated Ubuntu box with PHP 5.3.10. Here's what `phpinfo()` says about my ImageMagick/Imagick install.

```
imagick module version => 3.1.0RC1
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Calling `convert source.gif -resize 123x123 dest.gif` works on the server—the issue seems to lie in the PHP call to ImageMagick rather than in the installation itself. Answers to [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2460/gif-animations-not-appearing) indicate that GIF issues disappear with the proper configuration, but I fail to see what's lacking in this particular setup.

Comment: Any chance this is a public box we could get CP/FTP access to , to see what's going on?  If so, can you send some credentials over to support@buildwithcraft.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating PHP on the server to at least 5.4 fixed the issue. This is apparently [a known Imagick issue](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues/20) with PHP 5.3.

Comment: Ohh... nice find!

Comment: @BradBell Thanks again for the quick support offer. It makes Craft a trusty platform to build on.