# Animated GIFs not animating - sometimes

Tags: assets, image-transforms, image

I've had trouble getting animated GIFs to transform properly on my Craft site.

I've installed Imagick on my server, and set $imageDriver to imagick explicitly. This seems to have allowed some GIFs to transform but not others. I've tried GIFs I've made myself in Photoshop, and GIFs found online, with completely mixed results. No rhyme or reason to it at all as far as I can tell.

Examples:

A GIF that resized correctly: http://craft.kingzog.com/img/_thumbnail/OH-TEE.gif

And one that didn't: http://craft.kingzog.com/img/_thumbnail/tennis_gif.gif

(I'm not allowed to post too many links, but of course you can remove /_thumbnail from the URLs to view the original, still-animated GIFs).

I'm stumped. Anyone have any knowledge about file formatting, config or anything else that might help?

Comment: Did you see this question: ["GIF animations garbled and static"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/5013/125)?

Comment: That issue was to do with an old version of PHP, this server runs php5.5.7 [PHP INFO](http://craft.kingzog.com/phpinfo.php)

Answer (score 2):

I'd make sure you're running the latest stable version of both the [Imagick library](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php) as well as the [Imagick PHP module](http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=imagick).

It's possible that older version had bugs in them which might explain what you're seeing.